# Show multiple values for a day in Highcharts time series

Tags: highcharts

I have an array of information. Each value is from either the beginning or the end of each day.

To illustrate this, take this array: `[5, 18, 7, 2]`. 5 and 18 were recorded on June 7th, with 5 recorded in the morning, and 18 in the evening. 7 and 2 were recorded June 8th.

How would I represent this information in a Highcharts time series chart?

Comment: Do you have a timestamp for those values?

Comment: The values were imported all at once, so unfortunately the timestamps have an inaccurate time. The date itself is accurate, but the time is not.

Comment: I guess the more important question is, how do you *want* to represent this on a chart? How to do it depends on what you want from it.

Comment: You can use [pointInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval) or pairs [x,y] for each point.

Answer (score 1):

my naive implementation would be to just space the points equal distance across the day.

For instance, if you have 2 points on June 7th:

```
 var seriesData = [];
 var milliInDay = 86400000; // milliseconds in a day
 var startOfDay = 1402099200000; // javascript timestamp for start of June 7th
 var numberOfPointsInDay = 2;
 var daySpacing = milliInDay / numberOfPointsInDay;
 seriesData.push([startOfDay + daySpacing, 5]);
 seriesData.push([startOfDay + (daySpacing * 2), 18]);
```